# TableView show Wait Cursor while select all (Ctrl - A)

Tags: javafx, tableview, selection

We have a `TableView` showing a large amount of data. It is a typical use case to select the whole table for some further processing.
This can be done via `Ctrl A` keybinding. Since the table content is quite large, this selection can take a second or two, which tends to irritate users.
How can I show a Wait Cursor between pressing the keys and the time the selection is actually showing up?

Displayed data might be lazily fetched, depending on the RAM available, so this might be a source of the delay. But I am not sure about this, it might as well be just the "selection" itself.

I am imagining to catch the select-all-event, call `scene.setCursor(WAIT)`, `selectionModel.selectAll()` and `scene.setCursor(DEFAULT)` again. But I don't know how to do that nor if that would be even the right approach.

Comment: Do you know the source of the delay? If it's just the rendering then it is probably all done on the UI thread, so there isn't really anything you can do about it... If there's some background fetching though it may work.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I have updated the question.

Comment: Do you use `tableView.getSelectionModel().selectAll()`? If the data is lazily fetched do you perhaps fetch all the data or even larger parts. In this case your problem is impossible to identify without more info... When/how is the data fetched???

Comment: I use Crtl A ;) this is why I cannot call setcursor() before, at least I don't know how to hook into the selection via keyboard process.

Comment: How much data is there? (Specifically, if you call `table.getItems().size()`, what range of values would you expect to have for that?) Is the lazy fetching being done on a background thread?